# Is it possible that the DPI in Excel has been changed per window?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following problem. I have opened two workbooks. Each in a seperate window. Now, one of the workbook has a different column width of 8 than the other.

[image: Width of a cell in column P]

[image: Width of a cell in column P]

Could someone tell me what is going on or how to revert the former one back to the latter one?

Zoom has been set to 100% in both cases.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column width number is relative to the font size, not an absolute unit of measure. It is linked to the font of the Normal style and denotes the number of characters that would fit into that column. Since most fonts are proportional and not fixed width, things get a bit more complicated, though.

See here for details: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/determine-column-widths

In the screenshot below, the Normal font for the workbook at the top is Calibri 14, the one at the bottom is Calibri 11. All visible columns have a column width of 8.

[image]

**Edit**  To change the normal style, click the Home ribbon > Styles panel > Right click the Normal Style and select **Modify**. In the next dialog, click the Format button and change the font size in the dialog.

[image]

Comment: Could you also indicate how to change the font of the normal style so I can switch to the most appropriate display?

Comment: I added more detail to my answer.